# Speeding up Pandas DataFrame filter

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a 15 million rows DataFrame where I need to get about 10,000 smaller sub dataframes by splitting the original over the values of one specific column (`splitting_col`)

What I have:

```
conditions = [big_df.splitting_col == value for value in list(big_df['splitting_col'].unique())]
smaller_dfs = [big_df[condition] for condition in conditions]
```

I don't really need the data to be in a DataFrame, but I will always start with `big_df` as a DataFrame.
Is there a way to speed up this process?

Comment: Why do you need all of these dataframes stored in a list? Is there anything you plan to do after? It's possible this list of sub dataframes could be completely unecessary

Comment: @ALollz what I really do is applying a function to create an object out of the sub_dataframe in the list comprehension so I get a list of objects. So the code I wrote replicates my problem in an easier way to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and a list comprehension.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(410112)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 4, (8, 2)),
                  columns=['data', 'grouping_col'])

[gp for _, gp in df.groupby('grouping_col')]
#[   data  grouping_col
# 3     2             1
# 6     1             1
# 7     2             1,
#    data  grouping_col
# 0     3             2
# 1     3             2
# 4     2             2,
#    data  grouping_col
# 2     1             3
# 5     3             3]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** As ALollz suggested, **Group by** gave me the best performance:

```
smaller_dfs = [gp for _, gp in big_df.groupby('splitting_col')]
```

Using **ALollz** answer and a **Condition Filter/Append/Drop** approach I measured the performance like this:

```
import timeit

setup = """
import pandas as pd
splitting_col_list = [j for j in range(100) for i in range(10000)]
values_list = [2*i for i in splitting_col_list]
big_df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(splitting_col_list, values_list)), columns=['splitting_col', 'values'])
"""

test1 = """
conditions = [big_df.splitting_col == value for value in list(big_df['splitting_col'].unique())]
smaller_dfs = [big_df[condition] for condition in conditions]
"""
test2 = """
conditions = [big_df.splitting_col == value for value in list(big_df['splitting_col'].unique())]
smaller_dfs = []
for condition in conditions:
    smaller_dfs.append(big_df[condition])
    big_df = big_df.drop(big_df[condition].index)
"""
test3 = """
smaller_dfs = [gp for _, gp in big_df.groupby('splitting_col')]
"""



print('Condition list comprehension:', timeit.timeit(test1, setup, number=10))
print('Condition and drop:', timeit.timeit(test2, setup, number=10))
print('Group by:', timeit.timeit(test3, setup, number=10))
```

Console Output:

```
    Condition list comprehension: 1.7542460000000002
C:\Users\x\x\x\x\envs\lib\timeit.py:15: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  -n/--number N: how many times to execute 'statement' (default: see below)
C:\Users\x\x\x\x\envs\lib\timeit.py:16: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  -r/--repeat N: how many times to repeat the timer (default 5)
Condition and drop: 5.7606202
Group by: 0.44012989999999874
```

After playing around with the test I found out that Group By approach wins by far with big DataFrames